# I know how to link a custom url to an image, BUT how do I

Tags: image, hyperlink

On my wordpress.org site, I have a free quote button/image under every product we carry (1000's+), I need it to link to our contact us page. Is there a quick way to do this or will I have to go in & edit each button/image individually? I am using PHP server-side language.

Comment: Which server-side language are you using? Do you keep record of products in a database? Provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is copying it on all of the products! The link will remain!